# Android App Version Fragmentation - How To Handle?

Tags: android

About half a year ago we released a huge update to the app, and with this introduced new permissions to the app (GPS / Bluetooth related, etc)

Half a year is plenty of time for users to update, however in Google dev console we still shows a large percentage, about 30% of the user base still using the old version.

I'm assuming this is due to

1. New Permissions require Manual updates, users must to hit 'Accept' before installing the
   update, and new update is being bypassed by Auto-Update
2. Some users have disabled Auto-Update and never update at all
3. Probably some percentage of old / abandoned devices

We're looking to address #1 as we experienced that making changes to app's permissions creates fragmentation pockets within the user base.

A potential solution would be to show a periodic "in-app" notification prompting users to update. But the problem is how to release an app update only reaching those old version users without impacting current users, as we cannot remove new permissions.

A hypothetical approach would be an in-between update, but the dev console does not allow lower app versions.

Are there any solutions available for reaching stuck users on old versions, or any work arounds that could be recommended?

Comment: do you have any analytics on who these left behind users are? e.g operating system versions, screen sizes, device names?

Comment: We have Google Analytics plugged in, and what's available in the Dev Console. How would we grab those stats, also how would it help with the update? Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: Potential solution is to look at contact info of your user base (if you have it - email for registration or something similar) as a means of contacting users to notify them of the update. Then in future versions look to have the in app notification to try and reduce the number of scenario 1. Just a thought if you have access to the data.

Answer (score 1):

> New Permissions require Manual updates, users must to hit 'Accept'
>   before installing the update, and new update is being bypassed by
>   Auto-Update

I don't think you can bypass the prompt for the manual acknowledgment.

My best practices for using adding new permissions are:

- Always adding creative release notes to explain why I need these permissions, so the user will download the update.
- Luckily with Android M your users won't experience this

> Are there any solutions available for reaching stuck users on old
>   versions, or any work arounds that could be recommended? Thanks!

Once a user is lost, it is very hard to get them back.

You can use your analytics to determine which popular devices are using your old app version.

Depending on the time/resources you have, multiple apks and segmentation based on devices can help you in this situation.

http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html

> A potential solution would be to show a periodic "in-app" notification
>   prompting users to update.

This logic can live client side and if done right users running your current version do not see that.

Hope this helps or leads you in the you are hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I managed this sort of situation by having the app periodically check-in with my backend server to report the app version number.  The server would check the app version number against what the server supports and if an upgrade was required the server would return a message that the app would then prompt to the user asking them to update.  Obviously that doesn't help you with your existing 30% of users but it might help in the future.

I would also think it would help to release an update that targets Marshmallow and then you could use the newer permission model and prompt users for what permissions you need.  I would think that would then allow the 30% on the older version of your app to auto-update or update without having to confirm permission changes in the play store.  Those users would then be prompted in the app for whatever permissions you require.